# App that redirect to other Apps

Tags: redirect, facebook-apps

In my app, am I allowed to redirect users to other apps (of course if they choose to do this). It would be like in an affiliate model : if I send someone to the app X, and the user choose to use it, the owner of app X pays for that.

I'm not sure that it is allowed on Facebook, and I will be very grateful for those which would help me find the answer regarding this particular important issue for me.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No problem if The app x is in Facebook

> > 11.Apps on Facebook may not integrate, link to, promote, distribute, or
> >     redirect to any app on any other competing social platform.
>
> 12 . The
>   primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be
>    to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an
>    external site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I read facebook platform policies they say :

"E. Advertisements and Cross-Promotions

You must not include advertisements or promotions, cross-promote other applications, or provide web search functionality in content distributed through Facebook social channels.

You can only utilize advertising or similar monetization related products or services from companies that appear on this list within Apps on Facebook.com."

So I don't understand. Isn't what I'm talking about like some kind of cross-promoting other applications ?

Comment: it says `through Facebook social channels.` 
not in the app itself (you cant send notification or message or post to wall about advertisement)
many ad providers are working with fb and some of them are advertising Other apps :)